# SVN: Poor perfomance after moving working copy to another machine

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I am trying to move/copy a SVN working copy from one linux machine to another. From researching similar questions/answers, this seems possible by simply moving the entire folder (along with the .svn subdirectory). I have implemented a solution that performs this copy using tar.

On source machine:

```
tar -cpz -f checkout_directory.tar.gz checkout_directory
```

On destination machine (after copy of the tarball):

```
tar -xpz -f checkout_directory.tar.gz
```

This achieves the goal of moving the working copy to the destination machine; however the performance of svn operations becomes drastically slower. For example, an `svn status` on the original machine takes < 1 minute, but takes ~1 hour on the destination machine. The entire folder is ~50GB, but these timings include clearing out the linux buffers/caches and similar hardware/load on each machine.

I can mitigate the performance hit by doing an `svn cleanup` on the destination machine, but this operation also takes ~1 hour. I suspect this updates the change times that SVN uses to determine whether or not local changes have been made.

Is there a better way of doing this?

P.S. I would like to avoid to doing `svn checkout` on the destination machine because this must be done on many machines.

Comment: It seems like a problem related with SVN cache.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, could you clarify what you mean by SVN cache. Is there anything I can do to fix it without the cleanup command?